# projection of a matrix $U$ with respect to the spectral norm of $UU^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm reading [a paper](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~klivescu/papers/arora_etal_allerton2012.pdf) that defines a projector as follows:

$P_{\perp}(U)$ is a "projection" (slight abuse of termninology) with respect to the spectral norm of $UU^T$ onto the set of $d\times d$ matrices with $k$ eigenvalues equal to 1 and the rest equal to 0. Apparently this can be achieved somehow by using Gram-Schmidt.

I'm confused as to what this means precisely. Can someone enlighten me with a simple example?

Comment: Could you tell where in the paper this is defined?

Comment: III.A. first paragraph

Answer (score 1):

The $U$ is the matrix of left singular vectors and is orthogonal. You want to enforce this after the descent step. Since you want only to retain $k$ singular values you only need $k$ orthonormal vectors in $U$. This is equivalent to saying $k$ eigenvalues of $UU^T$ are one and the rest are zero.

**update:** The orthonormality might be irrelevant. I think the projection is meant to be $$\mathcal{P}_\perp(X)=\arg\min_{U\in\mathcal{U}_k}\Vert XX^T-UU^T\Vert,$$ where the norm is the spectral norm, and $\mathcal{U}_k$ is the set of matrices with $k$ eigenvalues equal to one and the rest zero.

Comment: Meaning take the SVD of $UU^T$ and just keep the first k columns?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is equivalent to SVD  because the norm used to measure the error is the spectral norm. I think it would've been the SVD if the norm was the Frobenius norm (I have to double check).

Comment: They say further down that the Gram-Schmidt procedure will find the projection. Not seeing that.

Comment: This is the closest thing I can interpret from what's written in the paper. I can say it certainly selects the "largest eigenvector" of $XX^T$ in $U$, but if the difference of largest and the second largest eigenvalues is greater than one, the remaining columns of $U$ seem to be not that constrained.